# Unable to choose desktop environment 14.04

Tags: login, environment

I don't have the dropdown menu in the login screen.
This question was posed earlier but closed as not being reproducible.
Guess what? I have that problem also.
Any KNOWLEDGEABLE suggestions would be appreciated.
Generally, I've installed a bunch of desktops, but am unable to access any of them.

Comment: What display manager?

Comment: Dose it happen while your system is coming from suspend or when you turn on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just install the desktop after. Have you tried just finishing the install and running:

```
sudo apt-get install unity #or preferred desktop
```

And then restarting?